# R read_excel readxl sometimes incorrectly converts numbers to dates

Tags: r, excel, readxl

When I use read_excel to import data from Excel to R, some numeric columns are automatically converted to dates.

```
# e.g.
5600 to 1915-05-01
```

Is there a way to turn of this feature? Other than using "col_types" argument in read_excel.

Comment: col_types is it mate

Comment: what's your aversion to using an argument explicitly designed for the purpose you're after? I must be missing something

Comment: The question is, what is in your data that makes read_excel think it's a date? If it were only numbers, this probably wouldn't happen

Comment: @MichaelChirico I'm uploading multiple files (30+ excels) using a for loop, and they can have different structures (e.g. column names, number of columns). Therefore, defining col_types one-by-one is possible but not quite efficient.

Comment: @docendodiscimus That's a really good point. I've checked the data on Excel before posting this question, and the column only contains 1 to 5 digits whole numbers.

Comment: understood, and it's a valid concern.  I agree with @docendodiscimus in this case -- it's worth exploring what's led read_excel astray

Comment: @MichaelChirico - what's led `read_excel()` astray is the fact that date times are a special form of numeric, so it's not easy for the type guesser to distinguish between a number and a number that's really a date.

Comment: @LenGreski certainly the vast majority of data sets being used today are not using data from 1915... I know nothing will be perfect for this case, but improvements are always something to look out for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readxl` package, like `readr` for raw data files, has a type guesser to determine how to read columns in an Excel spreadsheet. As noted in the package vignette, the guessing process is not perfect, especially as it relates to date formats because they are stored as a special type of number.

[image]

As stated in the package documentation (as well as the comments on the OP), the way to avoid inaccurate guesses from the column type guesser is to explicitly specify the column types with the `col_types` argument on `read_excel()`.

Comment: if the type guesser is failing, probably the algorithm can be improved. I encourage OP to file an issue on GitHub and share their data if possible